# Php Memory Exhausted.Unable to Resolve

Tags: php

I am using PHP to read a really large table(8,00,000 rows,130 columns) from Hive.
I am getting some Allocated memory exhausted error.I have seen the same question been answered in Stackoverflow by setting memory_limit=512M(say) in php.ini file.

I did the same and restarted the service.But still the same error pops out.Any suggestion would be of great help.

Comment: And you select all records with your query?

Comment: ya I need all of those records

Comment: And you stuff all those records into memory at once? Is that necessary? Can you not process them row by row and then discard them?

Comment: Chances are that you do not need them all at once, so you should google for "php database iterator" (an iterator being something that processes a large result set without loading all of it into memory).

Comment: I need all those records for drawing charts using D3.js

Answer (score 2):

There could be several problems:

- Your MySQL uses too much memory / resources
- Your result list in PHP is too large. For example if you've a collection of large objects, your result list can have 8.000.000 objects in it

It's better to paginate your data. Below I'll explain that.

### Pagination

Pagination in query is limiting the results (`LIMIT FROM, SIZE'). The query looks like this:

```
SELECT foo, bar FROM table LIMIT 0, 100
```

So you get small query results, less memory and resource use.

Read the full story here: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination

### Performance

To avoid performance issues, determine for archiving data. Let's me give an example:

- Use a temp table, within you save data for (for example) 1 month
- All data, older than 1 month, should be moved to an 'archive' table
- Read from the temp table, it's fast

### Future

You possibly expect more and more data. So it's a good thing to look further. Using `Elasticsearch` or `Solr`, you can query, filter, analyse and aggregate millions of documents in milliseconds.